# How to create a condition if one of the values ​contains number and string values ​stored in the table using php?

Tags: php, mysql

So I have my field named `"jumlah_pengikut"` one of table, which results in the value of `"1 Orang"` and I want if the value captures `number at one of the strings`, `then only displays "1 Orang"`. If not, `then only displays "Html Table"` with php function or condition.

```
<?php
if ($row['jumlah_pengikut'] == (substr($row['jumlah_pengikut']))); {
 echo (substr($row['jumlah_pengikut']));
} else {
#html table
}
```

Comment: @perelin already sir, I have used this tool before than you meant ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here a function is a wrapper for a preg_match, that checks the start of a string for a number match:

```
<?php

function string_starts_with_number($str)
{
    return preg_match('/^[0-9]+/', $str);
}

$row['foo'] = '10 Green Bottles.';
if(string_starts_with_number($row['foo'])) {
    echo $row['foo'];
} else {
    echo 'Something else.';
}
```

Output:

```
10 Green Bottles.
```

Comment: sir, your answer is match... but  what if my value already exists or is saved in the previous table, meaning I have to take "10 Green Bottles / 1 Orang" based on the values ​​that are available from the table.

Comment: @azemloka perhaps try and clarify your question.  Table is a bit ambiguous here, as you mention HTML table, and mysql, so could mean database tables.  Feel free to edit your original question.

Comment: Well sir, i copied.